# Inject object into another object

Tags: ios, swift

These are my simple class structures. I pull states based on user id and state may or may not have cities and City may or may not have zips. These are based on how user is setup. I retrieve data from my website successfully, however I have problem injecting zips to cities and cities to states. I am able to display only states in my table view. City and Zip objects are empty when try to use print them on the screen. Any idea why I can't inject cities and zips into state object?

```
class State {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var city:[City]?

    init(id:Int, name:String, city:[City]?){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
    }
}

class City {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var zip:[Zip]?

    init(id:Int, name:String, zip:[Zip]?){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.zip = zip
    }
}  

class Zip {
    var id:Int
    var name:String

    init(id:Int, name:String){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I use them to generate a table view with `getStateCityZip()` method. I pull data from my website.

```
// These are table view controller class properties
var state = [State]()
var city = [City]()
var zip = [Zip]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     getStateCityZip()
}

func getStateCityZip(){

    // Get States
    getStatesByUserID(userID) {
        (result)->() in
        var states = JSON(result)
        for index in 0... states.count - 1 {
            let statesID: Int = states[index]["stateID"].intValue
            let statesName: String = states[index]["title"].stringValue


            // Get Cities by State ID
            self.getCities(stateID) {
                (result) -> () in
                let cities = JSON(result)
                for index in 0...cities.count - 1 {
                    let cityID: Int = cities[index]["cityID"].intValue
                    let cityName: String = cities[index]["title"].stringValue


                    // Get zip by city id
                    self.getZips(cityID){
                        (result) -> () in
                        var zips = JSON(result)

                        for zipIndex in 0... zips.count - 1 {
                            let zipID: Int = zips[zipIndex]["id"].intValue
                            let zipName: String = zips[zipIndex]["zipName"].stringValue

                            // Append single zip into zips array
                            self.zip.append(Zip(id: zipID, name: zipName))
                        }
                    }

                    //Append a single city into cities array
                    self.city.append(City(id: cityID, name: cityName, zip: self.zip))
                }
            }

            // Append a single state that contains cities and zips into states array
            self.state.append(State(id: stateID, name: stateName, city:self.city ))
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is my table view `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. I am only able to see state name

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StateCityZipTableViewCell
    let state = self.state[indexPath.row]

    println(state.city?.count) // This prints 0

    cell.label.text = "\(state.name)" // This displays state name in my tableview cell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i would suggest you to give a breakpoint at this `let state = self.state[indexPath.row]` line and see what this state variable contains

Comment: As I said before, I can display state name but city is empty.

Comment: AFAIK the code looks fine. To analyse further it would be better if you post the JSON result as well. So that i can try the same

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086237/nested-asynchronous-responses/32086445?noredirect=1) Same question, but for simplicity I removed the zips post request. The problem here is that I applied the same logic from the previous answer for the 3rd post request, but it doesn't work.

Comment: okay if you are handling with async request. Remember to reload the data once you got all the responses. Are you sure you got all three responses before reloading table view.

Comment: One other thing I noticed — your `Zip` property in your `City` class is capitalized, meaning that it has the same name as your `Zip` class, and that it does not have the same name as the`self.zip` property you reference in your initializer. Was this a typo?

Comment: Good catch! Yes, it's a typo.